# Unable to add cocoapod dependancy in Custom framework - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, dependencies, cocoapods

## Report

### What did you do?

I have created podspec file for my custom Framework as:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.platform = :ios
  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.name = "CustomFramework"
  s.summary = "CustomFramework have all the wrapper API."
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.version = "1.0.0"
  s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.author = { "My Name" => "my.name@xyz.com" }
  s.homepage = "URL_LINK"
  s.source = { :git => "github_url_link", :tag => "#{s.version}"}

      s.dependency 'RealmSwift', '3.5.0'
      s.dependency 'Firebase/Core', '5.1.0'
      s.dependency 'Firebase/Firestore', '5.1.0'
      s.dependency 'PubNub','4.7.5'

  s.source_files = "CustomFramework/**/*.{swift}"
end
```

I am adding this Custom framework pod in the sample project as:

```
target 'customFrameworkSample' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'customFramework' , :path => 'Local_Path_for_customFramework.podspec'

  target 'customFrameworkSampleTests' do
    use_frameworks!
      pod 'customFramework' , :path => 'Local_Path_for_customFramework.podspec'
  end
end
```

### What did you expect to happen?

Pod should install properly and When sample project is Build, it should Run and not throw any error.

### What happened instead?

In the Sample project, error is thrown while importing firbase, RealmSwift files, etc.. in CustomFramework files.
[image: screen shot 2018-06-22 at 3 24 02 pm]

### CocoaPods Environment

cocoapod : 1.5.3

Comment: The Xcode parser doesn't see modules until after the first build.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify dependancies in your Podspec you are saying that **YOUR CUSTOM FRAMEWORK** is dependant on them. So the dependancies will only be available to reference within your framework. If you want the sample application to be able to reference Firebase then you will need to specify this within the sample application's podfile.

Documentation references:

[Podspec 'dependancies'](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)

[Podfile 'dependancies'](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#group_dependencies)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My custom framework is depended on these third-party frameworks. But when I include my custom framework inside a sample project using the pod, it will install all the pods successfully. But when I compile this project it gives above error in one of the custom framework's file.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added firebase library in Linked framework and libraries

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ryan110, I am not adding framework manually. I am using the pod for that. And when I install pod, it is generation Pod.framework inside the sample application's Linked framework and libraries.

Comment: just test it. i had this problem once which solved with this way.